# JQuery Ui Laravel is not a function

Tags: javascript, laravel-5

I have laravel layout

```
<html> //layout.blade.php
    <head>
        <script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
         @yield("content")
    </body>
</html>
```

And my view

```
@extends("layout")

@section("content")
<ul class="test">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
</ul>

<script>
     $(function() {
         $(".test").selectable();
     });
</script>
@endsection
```

My browser console always show me $(...).selectable is not a function

But if i make same without layout or without anonymous function this works

Comment: can you see the scripts in the browser?

Comment: Do you have the js folder directly in the public folder?

Comment: Yes i can in head tag, jquery work normal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think location is changed, because of route.
So you'd better to specify the correct url of "public" folder.

Please change like this.

```
<html> //layout.blade.php
    <head>
        <script src="{{URL::Asset('/js/jquery.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="{{URL::Asset('/js/jquery-ui.js')}}"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
         @yield("content")
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the above question this kind of problem usually arises when you try to pass an argument or route variable. So it would be wise to use `asset()` or `secure_asset()` while using your resources in the page.

```html
<html> //layout.blade.php
    <head>
        <script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('js/jquery-ui.js') }}"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
         @yield("content")
    </body>
</html>
```

Also please check the network section of your browser to make sure your resources are loading perfectly.